# How to change rows name to column name in dataframe using python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly

i have two dataframe:

```
  df1:
     colname   value
     gender     M
     status     business
     age        60

  df2:
     colname   value
     name       Susan
     Place      Africa
     gender     F
```

Is there  a way i can concatenate these two dataframe in a way as the expected output? I tried outer join but it doesnot work, Thank you in advance.

Note: No dataframes have always the same common attribute, and also I am trying to remove the colname and value column.

Expected output:

```
    gender status     age  name  Place 
0    M     business   60   0      0
1    F     0           0   Susan Africa
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert to Series with colname as index and `concat`:

```
dfs = [df1, df2]

out = pd.concat([d.set_index('colname')['value'] for d in dfs],
                axis=1, ignore_index=True).T
```

output:

```
colname gender    status  age   name   Place
0            M  business   60    NaN     NaN
1            F       NaN  NaN  Susan  Africa
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0).fillna(0).reset_index(drop=True)`

```
    gender    status   age   name   place
0      M    business   60      0       0
1      F           0    0  Susan  Africa
```

The `fillna` will replace the `NaN` values with 0.

Answer (score 0):

Below line will resolves your issue , you can use the pandas transpose function to solve this problem.

```py
df_new = pd.concat([df1,df2])
df_new.set_index("colname").T
```